# on MouseLeave event of button not getting proper image

Tags: c#, winforms

In form load I am using this code for all 6 buttons

```
private void Parent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
btnExam.SetBounds(btnExam.Location.X, btnExam.Location.Y, 175, 154); 
btnResult.SetBounds(btnResult.Location.X, btnResult.Location.Y, 175, 154); 
btnContactUs.SetBounds(btnContactUs.Location.X, btnContactUs.Location.Y, 175, 154); 
btnClasses.SetBounds(btnClasses.Location.X, btnClasses.Location.Y, 175, 154); 
btnCollegeList.SetBounds(btnCollegeList.Location.X, btnCollegeList.Location.Y,175,154); 
btnAbout.SetBounds(btnAbout.Location.X, btnAbout.Location.Y, 175, 154); 

GraphicsPath polygon_path = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding); 
polygon_path.AddPolygon(GetPoints(btnExam.ClientRectangle)); 
polygon_path.AddPolygon(GetPoints(btnResult.ClientRectangle)); 
polygon_path.AddPolygon(GetPoints(btnContactUs.ClientRectangle)); 
polygon_path.AddPolygon(GetPoints(btnClasses.ClientRectangle)); 
polygon_path.AddPolygon(GetPoints(btnCollegeList.ClientRectangle)); 
polygon_path.AddPolygon(GetPoints(btnAbout.ClientRectangle)); 

// Convert the GraphicsPath into a Region. 
Region polygon_region = new Region(polygon_path); 

// Constrain the button to the region. 
btnExam.Region = polygon_region; 
btnResult.Region = polygon_region; 
btnContactUs.Region = polygon_region; 
btnClasses.Region = polygon_region; 
btnCollegeList.Region = polygon_region; 
btnAbout.Region = polygon_region; 

}
```

and below code in all button's **"MouseEnter_Event"**

```
private void genericButton_event(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
var btn = (Button)sender; 
var imageName = btn.Name; 
btn.Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageName); 
}
```

Now if I am trying to use below code in **"MouseLeave_event"** than I am not getting the specified image ,I am getting no image than

```
private void genericButtonLeave_event(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
var btn = (Button)sender; 
var imageName = btn.Name + "L"; 
btn.Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageName); 
}
```

this all I am doing for button hover image to get change
please do suggest me how can I get image on `mouseLeave event`,where is the mistake

Comment: What's the error message? How do you store your `images` in the `Resource`?

Comment: @KingKing I am just copying images from folder and pasting them in `Resource.resx` file of c# project , I am not getting any error ,on `mouseLeave event` I don't see image of that particular button,which I can see on form load